# Getting the error "Session [(null externalkey)] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions." when running on Selenium Grid

Tags: c#, nunit, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

Alright, so there are many similar questions to this one however I have exhausted all options that I have seen. I am hoping that someone will have more information to share.

**The Details**

I run five instances of test at a time, using Nunit (v3.10.1) on Chromedriver (v2.41) in the Selenium Grid (v3.14). I ***only*** get this error when running tests on the grid, this does not happen running locally. I typically use the default configuration for both the Selenium-Hub and the Selenium-Node.

**What I Have Tried**

I have spent quite some time researching this issue to find a solution to my problem, I have gotten a few results that had seemed promising but have not seemed to have had any effect.

- Increasing the Timeout/browserTimeout in the hub/node config
- Running 1 session at a time instead of 5
- Separating the tests onto different nodes on the same hub
- Adding the '--no-sandbox' property to Chromedriver
- Increasing wait times within my framework to give the driver more time to start up
- I have also tried catching the WebDriverException, but it seems to be uncatchable sometimes.
- Reverting to older versions of Selenium-Grid/Chromedriver

Let me know if there is any more information needed. I'm hoping that someone has some helpful information for this topic.

In my curiosity, I've noticed something I hadn't before. When I go to the Selenium-hub, more specifically to `hubaddress/wd/hub/sessions` I see the following as a result:

[image: Session Info]

As a driver closes and a new one opens, the Active Sessions [ext key ...] changes. So it seems that this exception always exists, and individual instances are not triggering it. (I think) Is it possible that NUnit cannot determine the reason for test failure and instead displays this exception?